# Recurrence relation: at least one 1 and first 1 occurs before first 0

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

**Find a recurrence relation with initial condition for the number of n-digit quaternary sequences (strings of 0,1,2 and 3) with at least one 1 and the first 1 occurring before the first 0 (possibly no 0s)**

I generally struggle with these recurrence relations questions, but here is my attempt:

Let $a_n=$ the number of “good sequences” that do have at least one 1 and the first one occurring before the first zero.

If the first digit is 3: $a_{n-1} $
If the first digit is 2: $a_{n-1} $
If the first digit is 1:$ a_{n-1}$
If the first digit is 0: 0
Thus: $a_n=3a_{n-1}$
Initial conditions: $ a_1=1,a_2=6$

Please comment on where I should fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if the first digit is $1$, there are some cases you haven't counted.  For example, $1,2$ and $1,0$ are valid sequences; but neither $2$ nor $0$ is a valid sequence.

In fact any sequence of length $n-1$ (valid or not) becomes valid if a $1$ is left-appended to the sequence.

Comment: Okay I hear what you are saying, thanks. So in order to fix that, would the sequnce when the first digit is 1 be $4^{n-1}$  but i think that might be wrong as it is not a reccurence relations... When I think maybe $4a_{n-1}$ please give more hints.

Comment: would $a_n=2a_{n-1}+3a_{n-2}+4^{n-2}$ be correct? I wrote all possiblities out for the first two digits  when starting with 1 and got to this solution. Please help!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $a_{n}=2a_{n-1}+4^{n-1}$?

Comment: Ahhh yes thanks. I think I split the sequences that start with 1 into sequences that start with 10,11,12, 13 but I now realise that is not necessary!